# Missing generator for $H^0(C, \, \omega_C^{\otimes 2})$, with $C$ is hyperelliptic of genus $3$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, hyperelliptic-curves

This is probably very classical and well-known, but I could not find the answer in the literature, so let me ask it here.

Let $C$ be a hyperelliptic curve of genus $3$, defined over the complex numbers and whose affine equation has the form $$y^2=g_{8}(x),$$ where $g_{8} \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ is a polynomial of degree $8$. Then, it is well-known that we can write a basis for the $1$-forms on $C$ as follows: $$H^0(C, \, \omega_C) = \left \langle \frac{dx}{y}, \, x\frac{dx}{y}, \, x^2 \frac{dx}{y} \right \rangle.$$
Setting $\xi_{i+1}:=x^i \frac{dx}{y}$, the $6$ elements $\xi_i \xi_j$, $1 \leq i \leq j \leq 3$, lie in $S^2H^0(C, \, \omega_C) \subset H^0(C, \, \omega_C^{\otimes 2})$. However, in this case the symmetrizatiom homomorphism $$\sigma \colon S^2H^0(C, \, \omega_C) \to H^0(C, \, \omega_C^{\otimes 2})$$ is *not* surjective (cf. Max Noether's Theorem), since there is a linear relation $$\sum \lambda_{ij} \xi_{ij}=0$$ between the $\xi_{ij}$, corresponding to the fact that the canonical map of $C$ is a double cover of a conic.

In fact, the image of $\sigma$ is $5$-dimensional, hence there is an additional generator $\eta \in H^0(C, \, \omega_C^{\otimes 2})$ which does not come from the symmetrization of the basis of $1$-forms.

> **Question.** Is it possible to express $\eta$ explicitly?

I really need to put my hands on some explicit construction of $\eta$: in fact, in my situation, I also have a finite group action on $C$, and I would like to check whether I can choose $\eta$ in such a way that it is $G$-invariant.

Comment: $\eta =\dfrac{dx^2}{y} $ should work.

Comment: @abx thanks for the answer. Why is this tensor in $H^0(C, \, \omega_C^{\otimes 2})$? In my affine chart, $\eta$ has no zeros. On the other hand, in the other chart given by ($u, \, v)=(1/x, \, y/x^4)$ the tensor becomes $(dv)^2/w$ that, again, has no zeros. But a section of $\omega_C^{\otimes 2}$ should vanish at $8$ points (with multiplicity). Am I missing something?

Comment: $\eta =y\cdot\left( \dfrac{dx}{y}\right)^2 $, so it vanishes at the 8 ramification points.

Comment: @abx I see, thanks again.

Comment: By the way, John Voight and I answer this question (and a lot more) in our book (but usually working with divisors instead); see 3.5 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.04657.pdf

Comment: Another (equivalent) way of obtaining the same result explained by @abx: you can write your curve $C$ as hypersurface of degree 8 in the weighted projective space $\mathbb{P}(1,1,4)$. Then $\omega_C^2 \cong \mathcal{O}(4)$, and therefore if you have to look for a basis of weighted homogeneous polynomials of degree 4. You have $Sym^4(x_0, x_1) \oplus y$, as requested.

Comment: thanks to everybody for the informative comments